# Триггер, для ограничение ввода данных. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, триггер

не могу вообще понять как сделать данное условие.... Может, нужно добавить еще какое-то поле, чтобы выполнить условие...

Хочу задать условия («Чтобы нельзя было указывать в таблица "Расписание" одновременно перебывание в разных аудитория на одном уроке (моего учителя в табл нагрузка»)

[image: Схема, на которую пытаюсь сделать.]

Comment: уникальный ключ на связку аудитория, день недели, урок

Comment: Хмм, не могу понять. Имеете введу, создать еще одну таблицу с этими колонками (аудитория, день недели, урок) и сделать внешний ключ в табл. расписание ?

Comment: нет, `create unique index Расписание_uniq on Расписание(Аудитория, День_недели, урок)`

Comment: Блин, вроде понял, с индексом проще. Но, что-то не могу додуматься какое условия нужно поставить в триггере, чтобы работала как мне надо. Имею введу, как именно проверить.
IF (id_нагрузка.id_teacher in Расписание_uniq)
then
То, что в голову идет, но как мне кажеться неверно

Comment: А зачем в триггере что то проверять ? Уникальный индекс сам не позволит вставить дублирующую запись

Comment: Понял, сейчас попробую разобаться в этом.

Comment: "как именно проверить. IF (id_нагрузка.id_teacher in Расписание_uniq) then" - читайте про Exists.

Comment: Проверить - выполнить запрос с введёнными данными в качестве параметров выражения условия отбора по пересечению, и убедиться, что возвращённый набор записей пуст. Запретить запись в таблицу не прошедших такую проверку данных - это сделает созданный уникальный индекс, при дублировании попытка записи приведёт к ошибке.

Comment: Ребят, у меня получаеться сделать, чтобы небыло дублирование. 
Одноко, когда я задаю,что мой учитель преподает к примеру ( на 1 уроке,в аудитории 111 и в понедельник) , а потом снова задаю ( на 1 уроке,в аудитории 112 и в понедельник) 
Тут Допускаеться ввод данных в обоих случаях, а у меня как бы учитель не может вести одновременно в разных аудиториях свой предмет... Как можно ограничить это ?